# how to retrieve markdown from remote git repository in Gatsby?

Tags: git, gatsby

The Gatsby website I am working on has its blog posts in the `content/posts` directory. I used `gatsby-source-filesystem` to access those files and turn them into pages.

```
//gatsby-config.js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${post_dir}/content/posts/`,
    name: "posts"
  }
},
```

Here is my gatsby-node.js.

```
//gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = boundActionCreators;
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` });

    const separtorIndex = ~slug.indexOf("--") ? slug.indexOf("--") : 0;
    const shortSlugStart = separtorIndex ? separtorIndex + 2 : 0;

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: `${separtorIndex ? "/" : ""}${slug.substring(shortSlugStart)}`
    });

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `prefix`,
      value: separtorIndex ? slug.substring(1, separtorIndex) : ""
    });
  }
};
```

I am using [gatsby-starter-personal-blog](https://github.com/greglobinski/gatsby-starter-personal-blog) starter in this project.

Now I want to move the `content/posts` directory into a separate repository where I can keep it public so that other people can edit them and send pull requests.

According to the `gatsby-source-filesystem` docs, I think  `createRemoteFileNode` method can be used to achieve this. I tried to use it, but several parameters need to pass into the function to create a node using `createRemoteFileNode`. I am struggling to use it in my context. I am very new to `Gatsby` can anybody help me to figure this out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This plugin seems to does what you describe: [gatsby-source-github](https://github.com/mosch/gatsby-source-github). Perhaps you can see its source for inspiration?

Comment: Thanks you @Derek  I will.

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to pull files from GitHub for Gatsby?

Answer (score 1):

I just had great success with [gatsby-source-git](https://github.com/stevetweeddale/gatsby-source-git). Tried [gatsby-source-github](https://github.com/mosch/gatsby-source-github) but while it worked I was getting some obscure errors. Though the latter will pull from a private repo if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, documentation for `gatsby-source-git` is poorly written.
the code from `gatsby-source-filesystem` will not work,because that plugin exposes several helper function e.g. createFilePath and `gatsby-source-git` does not have that and to add things to the mix, apparently nobody on internet is using it because there is no code example for `gatsby-node.js` file how to configure it. I am struggling with this for hours and I am close to give up.